# scp from remote host onto desktop, bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, scp

I want to copy a directory from a remote connection onto my desktop using the bash shell terminal, I tried:

```
scp -r haha@remotehost:dir1 /Desktop
scp -r haha@remotehost:dir1 /User/usrname/Desktop
```

But it tells me /Desktop: no such file or directory
If I do

```
scp -r haha@remotehost:dir1 .
```

it starts copying, but I don't know where the files are, can't find them.
Anybody know why?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `~/Desktop`.

`.` references the current working directory. You can see the full path for it by running `pwd`.

Specifying port:

```
man scp | grep port

scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
     -P port
             Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host.
```

`scp -P 1337 user@remote:foo.txt .`

Comment: I think it got copied onto the desktop of the remote connection, rather than the local desktop

Comment: When I run `pwd`, it tells me the directory of the remote connection

Comment: So that means I m copying into the remote connection?

Comment: You're logged into the terminal of the remote machine then. Run the command from your local computer.

If the remote machine must push the files to your local machine, explicitly specify the destination as user@local.domain:path (replacing local.domain with the destination IP)

Comment: I m scping from the local host and it says connection closed...

Comment: Try to ssh from the localhost using the same credentials. Is SSH running on a nonstandart port? If so you need to specify the port, see my edited post